# Limit of integrals of continuous functions

Tags: riemann-integration

If $g:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\lim\limits_{x 
 \rightarrow 0^+}\dfrac{g(x)}{x}$ exist and is finite, then prove that

$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1}g(x^n)dx= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{g(x)}{x}dx$$

This is problem from the book PROBLEMS IN REAL ANALYSIS- ADVANCE CALCULUS ON THE REAL AXIS by Titu Andreescu. The solution given on the book can't be understood by me. Please provide any alternative solution.

Comment: Please include the hypothesis that $g$ is continuous in the statement of the problem (putting it vaguely in the title isn't good enough) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $h:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by

$h(t) = \begin {cases} 
g(t)/t , & t \in (0,1] \\
lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}~g(x)/x, & t = 0
\end{cases}
$

Then $h$ is continuous and we can set
$H(x) = \int_0^1 h(t)dt.$

We have

$n \int_0^1g(x^n)dx=n \int_0^1x^nh(x^n)dx=xH(x^n)|_0^1- \int_0^1H(x^n)dx=H(1) - \int_0^1H(x^n)dx= \int_0^1 \frac{g(x)}{x}dx - \int_0^1H(x^n)dx.$

If $0 <  a<1$, then

$| \int_0^1H(x^n)dx| \leq \int_0^1|H(x^n)|dx 
= \int_0^a|H(x^n)|dx+ \int_a^1|H(x^n)|dx \leq a|H( \alpha _n^n)| + (1-a)M~~~~~~~(1)$

where $\alpha _n^n \in [0,a]$ and $M=max_{t \in [0,1]}|H(t)|.$

Consider $ \epsilon > 0$ such that $a>1 - \frac{\epsilon}{2M}$. Since $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|H( \alpha _n^n)|=0$ it follows that 
$a|H( \alpha _n^n)|< \epsilon /2$ for all positive itegers $n \leq N(\epsilon)$. Relation (1) yields

$| \int_0^1H(x^n)dx| \leq \epsilon /2 + (1-a)M < \epsilon /2 + (1-1+ \epsilon /2M)M= \epsilon$

Hence, $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 H(x^n)dx= 0$ and the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 5):

This is false. Consider $g(x) = x$, then
$$\int_0^1 g(x^n)dx =  \int_0^1 x^ndx =  \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}|_{x=0}^{x=1} = \frac{1}{n+1} \rightarrow 0$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{g(x)}{x}dx = \int_0^1 dx =  1$$

**Edit:** It is true however that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 n g(x^n)dx  = \int_0^1 \frac{g(x)}{x}dx$$

If you change variables you find 
$$\int_0^1 n g(x^n)dx = \int_0^1 y^{1/n} \frac{g(y)}{y}dy$$
and apply dominated convergence as 
$$y^{1/n} \frac{g(y)}{y} \rightarrow \frac{g(y)}{y} \text{ for } y\in(0,1]$$
which is true from our assumption on $g$.

Comment: Yes You are right..But the strange thing is this is proved in the book..and this is a reputed book..my goodness.. Could we trust anyone..it is really hurting..

Comment: Can you provide the proof? It's possibly a typo on the question.

Comment: Yes I can. Yeah I also think that there is a typo in the question.

Comment: Perhaps my edit fixes the mistake?

Comment: Yes yes u are right. Check the proof that I have given. It also confirms ur editing. Thank you.

Comment: Right, they just forgot the $n$ in the statement. No worries!